# Magento 1.4.1.1 ::: Exporting Products Leads to Fatal Error

Tags: magento, memory-leaks, magento-1.4

I am exporting around 1200 products to csv via Magento's export profile feature.

The export begins and then locks up.

php has this to work with:
max_execution_time 28000
memory_limit 1024M

I get this error:
[Wed Mar 23 12:48:33 2011] [error] [client 84.229.93.19] PHP Fatal
error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to
allocate 24 bytes) in
/path/to/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on
line 292, referer:
http://domain.com/index.php/admin/system_convert_profile/edit/id/10/key/598b0f0c45b13aba68a3fbe2b06a4d85/

Now, I know Magento 1.4.1.1 has a memory leak that directly affects this process,a nd I applied a patch to treat the issue:
http://blog.ewtechnologies.com/magento-2/magento-memory-leak-1-4-1-1/

But I still have this problem.

Does anyone have any other insights into this? Even if upgrading to 1.5.x will help?

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the memory for php until it succeeds as it buffers all the data to memory and is somewhat stupidly implemented